# MySQL Select Query running very slow

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that works but is very slow. I am guessing due to the amount of joins.

```
SELECT 
    order_header.order_head_id,
    order_header.order_date,
    order_header.status,
    suppliers.supplier,
    categories.category,
    order_header.user,
    order_header.sage_ref,
    SUM(order_lines.total_price) AS price
FROM
    order_header
        LEFT JOIN
    order_lines ON order_header.order_head_id = order_lines.order_head_id
        LEFT JOIN
    suppliers ON order_header.supplier_id = suppliers.supp_id
        LEFT JOIN
    categories ON order_header.category = categories.cat_id
WHERE
    order_header.status LIKE '%'
        AND order_header.order_head_id LIKE '%'
        AND order_header.user LIKE '%'
GROUP BY order_header.order_head_id
ORDER BY order_head_id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Results of the EXPLAIN query
[image]

SHOW CREATE TABLE results

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `order_header` (
  `order_head_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sage_ref` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `query_notes` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_head_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2249 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `order_lines` (
  `order_lines_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_head_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(65,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_price` decimal(65,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_lines_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3981 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `suppliers` (
  `supp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `supplier` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`supp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=161 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**SQL Version 5.6.30**

I am not great on MySQL and was wondering if anyone can see a way to improve the query so that it runs quicker.

Your help would be gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks,

John

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query. That said, `LIKE '%'` is a performance killer.

Comment: what do you are looking for with like '%' ..  ??

Comment: if i was you i won't worry about perfomance just jet, worry about a valid resultset first.. Because `SELECT 
    order_header.order_head_id,
    order_header.order_date,
    order_header.status,
    suppliers.supplier,
    categories.category,
    order_header.user,
    order_header.sage_ref,
    SUM(order_lines.total_price) AS price  ... GROUP BY order_header.order_head_id` is not the way how a GROUP BY should be used.

Comment: The LIKE % is there as I am running the query from a web form. The % can be replaced by a variable passed from the form. Worst case, the % is passed.

Comment: ... For that reason you should provide table structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` for every table involved in the question and `EXPLAIN <query>` output also because this is a performance question.. And provide example data and expected result read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) how to provide for a query which gives a valid resultset.. A MySQL version number can also be handy to be shared `SELECT VERSION():`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks Raymond. I have now included all the information you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: And the example data and expected results? See the link in mine other comment.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - What's wrong with the GROUP BY? All non-aggregated columns are functionally dependent on `order_head_id`.

Comment: Well @PaulSpiegel mine comments was made before the edit (CREATE TABLE added).. "All non-aggregated columns are functionally dependent on order_head_id" Why do you trust on that functionally dependency "feature" In MySQL because it works different between modern MySQL versions? [MySQL 5.6](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8AFhjjNPqoEr3qm6qU7bK8/0)  and [MySQL 5.7](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8AFhjjNPqoEr3qm6qU7bK8/2), MySQL 5.6 errors and MySQL 5.7, MySQL 8.0 are detecting functionally dependency in the query.. Motto of the story use ANSI valid SQL GROUP BY standard **always** just to be sure.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - It works. The result is well defined. And it is SQL99 compliant. Also including unnecessary columns in the GROUP BY clause can lead to performance issues. However - there is nothing to "worry about a valid resultset".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel " Also including unnecessary columns in the GROUP BY clause can lead to performance issues" Iám pretty sure SQL99 compliant is when you add all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` which you use in the `SELECT` .. MySQL's  functionally dependency is a extended GROUP BY "feature" on top of the SQL standard iám pretty sure that isn't defined in anny SQL standard correct me if iám wrong here.. functionally dependency is  relational database theory. sure it does not mean there is a SQL standard for it i believe MySQL/MariaDB (?) RDBMS which do functionally dependency

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Maybe it wasn't 99 - maybe it was 2003. But it doesn't matter. No one is forcing you to use MySQL features. But let other decide for themselves. What matters is that there is no problem with the result for the given query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i did research this some more about functionally dependency it was indeed menitioned in SQL 2003 (`ISO/IEC 9075-2:2003 in section 4.18  Functional dependencies`) you had it right this whole time... So it's not a MySQL/MariaDB only feature it's a real SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

It can make sense to wrap the first (left) join into a GROUP BY subquery. GROUP BY and LIMIT will limit the number of row which will be used in the following two joins:

```
SELECT 
    x.order_head_id,
    x.order_date,
    x.status,
    suppliers.supplier,
    categories.category,
    x.user,
    x.sage_ref,
    x.price
FROM (
    SELECT 
      order_header.supplier_id,
      order_header.category,
      order_header.order_head_id,
      order_header.order_date,
      order_header.status,
      order_header.user,
      order_header.sage_ref,
      SUM(order_lines.total_price) AS price
    FROM order_header
    LEFT JOIN order_lines ON order_header.order_head_id = order_lines.order_head_id
    WHERE order_header.status LIKE '%'
      AND order_header.order_head_id LIKE '%'
      AND order_header.user LIKE '%'
    GROUP BY order_header.order_head_id
    ORDER BY order_head_id DESC
    LIMIT 50
) x
LEFT JOIN suppliers  ON x.supplier_id = suppliers.supp_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON x.category    = categories.cat_id
ORDER BY order_head_id DESC
```